# Estimate Rows vs Actual Rows, what is the impact on performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

I have a query that performs very quickly but in production when server loads are high its performance is underwhelming.  I have a suspicion that it might be the Estimated Rows being much lower than the Actual Rows in the execution plan.  I know that server statistics are not stale.

[image: Sample SQL Sentry Plan]

I am now optimizing a new query and I worry that it will have the same problem in production.  The number of rows returned and the CPU and Reads are well within the designated thresholds my data admins require.  As you can see in the above SQL Sentry plan there are a few temp tables that estimate a single row but return 100 times as many rows.

My question is this, even when the number of rows are few, does a difference in rows by such a large percentage cause bottlenecks on the server's performance?  Secondary question, if the problem isn't a bad cached plan or stale stats, what other issues would cause a plan to show such a discrepancy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A difference between actual and estimated rows does not cause a "bottleneck" in the server.

The impact is on algorithms and resource allocation for the query.  SQL Server has multiple algorithms that it can use for things like JOINs and GROUP BYs.  The (estimated) size of the data is one of the primary items of information that it uses to choose the appropriate algorithm.

Choosing the wrong algorithm is not exactly a *bottleneck*, but it does slow the query down.  You would need to study the execution plan to see if this is happening in your case.

If you have simple queries that select from a single table, then there are many fewer options for the execution plan.  The only impact I can readily think of in this case would be using an full table scan rather than an index for filtering.  For your data sizes, I don't think that would make much of a difference.

Comment: That is really what I was trying to question.  It will allocate more resources and when we have multiple procs running that are poorly optimized, this over allocation of resources, I believe, is causing large wait times and increased CPU cycles on our server during the busy times of the month. This is the bottleneck I was wondering about.

Comment: Also, I understand the data size of this procedure is very small, and this procedure is run infrequently.  We have other procedures that I have been assigned  to optimize- one of these, for example, in a single day used 21 million CPU Cycles and over 3 Billion reads.  I have reduced it to where it is 7 million CPU and 10 million reads but I think the estimated rows/actual rows is the hurdle I need to solve next.

Comment: @DRT . . . You may be better off just using compiler hints to choose the right algorithms for joins and group bys.

Answer (score 0):

> Estimate Rows vs Actual Rows, what is the impact on performance?

If there is huge difference between `Estimate Rows` and `Actual Rows` then you need to worry about that query.

There can be no of reason for this.

1. Stale Statistics
2. Skewed data distribution : Here Statistics is updated, but it is skewed.Create  Filtered Statistics for those index will help.
3. Un-Optimize query :Poorly written query.Join condition are in wrong manner.